# Cancel the custom action execution and Rollback using wix burn Boostrapper UI

Tags: wix, custom-action, bootstrapper, burn

I am trying to create wix burn bootstrapper that install my msi. I am using Wix 3.7.
I have few custom actions with my msi. If I cancel the setup while 1st (or any) CA running, all other CA are called by sequence after the execution of that particular CA. I have set the value of Execute attribute of all of my CA is immediate **Execute="immediate"**

Also I have set a code **Result.Cancel**  in ApplyExecuteProgress callback.
In the log file I have found errors like this:

```
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:759]: I/O on thread 4844 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:759]: I/O on thread 5164 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:759]: I/O on thread 6040 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:759]: I/O on thread 2908 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:759]: I/O on thread 6272 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:760]: I/O on thread 6280 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:760]: I/O on thread 6612 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:760]: I/O on thread 4076 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
 MSI (s) (10:34) [07:34:58:760]: I/O on thread 6596 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
```

Could anyone please tell me any suggestion for stopping CA?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your custom action has thread running around doing I/O that cannot be canceled. You need to look at your code and determine what is causing the issue. This is very specific to your code.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will check why this issue happened. I have some more information regarding this, i did the same steps in msi installation. I just install the **msi** setup and cancel the installation while CA execution, in this above mentioned error is shown in log file and the installation get stopped after the execution that particular CA and shows **Installation failure** in log entry. While i do the same from my **bootstrapper** UI, control goes to remaining CA and also shows log as **Installation completed successfully.** Could you please tell me where the problem is occured for this issue?